# application-defined exception

Tags: c++, c++builder

Could anybody explain me what does the following **"Debugger Fault Notification"** mean in C++ Builder XE:

```
"Project ... faulted with message: 'application-defined exception (code 0x0eefface) at 0x755ad36f. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue."
```

It occurs only when I need to throw an exception - the calling of throw raises this error.
I can't find any information about this problem.

throwing of the exception:

```
#define MY_ERROR_CODE 0xE0000046

throw TMyTrouble(MY_ERROR_CODE, "My error message"); // calling of this raises the application-defined exception...
```

catching:

```
try{
Function(); // function that raises the exception TMyTrouble
}
catch(...){ // this catch should catch the exception but it doesn't
// do something
throw; // throw to upper layer
}
```

definition of exception:

```
class TMyTrouble{
      public:
        TMyTrouble(int errorCode = 0xFFFFFFFF, AnsiString errorMessage = "Unknown error") { FMessage = errorMessage; FCode = errorCode;}
        __property AnsiString Message = {read = FMessage};
        __property unsigned long Code = {read = FCode};

      private:
        unsigned long FCode;
        AnsiString FMessage;
    };
```

Comment: Is there a `catch` somewhere that handles the thrown exception?

Comment: yes, but it catches nothing - thats what is strange

Comment: Can you post the `throw` and the `catch` code plus the exception definition?

Comment: There is a difference between C++ exceptions and SEH exceptions, even though the latter are usually used to implement the C++ exceptions on Windows. Either way, you supply no piece of code (for example the `throw` and the `catch`) in a minimalistic sample. Which you should do ...

Comment: How do you know it is not caught? It is rethrown, meaning there must be a further `catch` somewhere up the call chain.

Comment: Because I have a breakpoint in the catch. When i am trying to throw TMyTrouble I get the fault ("application-defined exception..."), that is not cateched by the catch and than no other exception is thrown and the Function is ended with no exception... (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: All this is happened in Debug mode, in Release mode the application totally falls down when it throws the TMyTrouble

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is perfectly normal behavior.  What you are seeing is called a "first chance exception" message.  The message is being reported by the debugger before the app sees the exception.  This is evident by the text in the message: "Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue".  Just do what the message says - simply press F9, or press the Run button on the toolbar, to continue execution and the exception will be passed back to the app for normal handling in its `try/catch` blocks.

Comment: So why it is not normally catched by the catch statement? In Release mode the throwing of the exception causes the application to fall down, what is not normal because throwing an exception with no catch statement causes an error dialog, but not FALLING DOWN the application...

Comment: If I press F8 (Step forward) after the "first chance exception" message is shown like you said, than my exception is not executed and the program continues with that what is after the throw statement

Comment: `catch(...)` does not always catch everything.  For instance, since BCB6, it does not catch VCL `Exception` objects correctly.  Try catching `TMyTrouble` explicitally instead: `catch (const TMyTrouble &e)`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just the debugger's way of saying, "I just noticed an exception was thrown, what do you want to do?"

If you don't want the debugger to stop when you throw an exception, there are settings for that.

If you choose contine, your code should then catch it.

Comment: I don't think so... Debugger informs you about throwing an exception as you said, but this looks like some internal error of throw procedure, because the throwing is not executed - it is not catched! It looks like the throw procedure throws some internal exception - but it is strange, because it should be catched by the catch statement as well, but it is not... :(

Comment: No, this is definately the debugger reporting a first-chance exception before the app sees it. This is evident by this text in the message: "Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue".  This is perfectly normal behavior.  Do what the message says.  Press F9 to continue execution, and the exception will be passed to the app for handling.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize to all of you, problem was in the construction before the throw statement:

```
byte value;
sscanf(buffer, "%02x", &value);
```

Can you see the problem?
The `sscanf` function returns for that format string `"%02x"` a long value (4 bytes), but I have a byte variable `value` (1 byte) - so 3 bytes were written somewhere and the stack was damaged (or something), what causes my problems...

Thank you for helping